# Get the current user information through nexus 3 api

Tags: sonatype, nexus3, nexus3-api

Nexus 3 offers some API (https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api) but no endpoint seems to exist to get the current user information (name, email, ...)

I don't have an admin access, so I can't use `/security/users` endpoint

Is there some API that is not documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that nexus 3 and an (undocumented?) internal API. The following endpoint can be used to retrieve the current user:

```
/internal/ui/user
```